# Wrong DigestValue: "Hash values do not match" XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml, hash, xml-signature, c14n

I am trying to sign an XML file and in all the requests I make I get the error "Hash values ​​do not match."

This is my XML

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://ws.hc2.dc.com/v1">
    <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-2DCB6C8D1D61184E481607306401918160" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <v1:consultarHC2>
            <v1:solicitud>
                <v1:clave>75URP</v1:clave>
                <v1:identificacion>888888881</v1:identificacion>
                <v1:primerApellido>PRUEBAS</v1:primerApellido>
                <v1:producto>64</v1:producto>
                <v1:tipoIdentificacion>1</v1:tipoIdentificacion>
                <v1:usuario>830514264</v1:usuario>
            </v1:solicitud>
        </v1:consultarHC2>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is the DigestValu calculated in SoapUI **oyEmssDWuGqQejZ4krpKmv2/KJc=** however the value calculated in PHP is **BzmNrO3Pdl1R6I1MWHw/QG5cn08=**

My canonicalized Body element (c14n) looks as follows:

```
<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://ws.hc2.dc.com/v1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-2DCB6C8D1D61184E481607306401918160">            <v1:consultarHC2>              <v1:solicitud>                <v1:clave>75URP</v1:clave>                <v1:identificacion>888888881</v1:identificacion>                <v1:primerApellido>PRUEBAS</v1:primerApellido>                <v1:producto>64</v1:producto>                <v1:tipoIdentificacion>1</v1:tipoIdentificacion>                <v1:usuario>830514264</v1:usuario>              </v1:solicitud>            </v1:consultarHC2>          </soapenv:Body>
```

The DigestValue is being calculated in PHP as follows:

```
//$data is equal to XML
$data = str_replace(["\r", "\n"], ['', ''], $data);
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$doc->loadXML($data);
$bodyNode = $doc->getElementsByTagName('Body')->item(0);
$canonicalized = $bodyNode->C14N();
//OR
$canonicalized = $bodyNode->C14N(true);
//OR
$canonicalized = $bodyNode->C14N(false,false);
$digest = base64_encode(hash('SHA1', $canonicalized, true));
//OR
$digest = base64_encode(pack("H*", sha1($canonicalized)));
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong, I need help I have not yet managed to get the generated value in SoapUI.

Comment: were you able to resolve your issue?